# How to use regex to remove a string and its corresponding punctuation?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to remove the words `"bro"` and `"girl"` from a string, and all corresponding punctuation and spaces. For example, `"What's up, bro? That's cool"` becomes `"What's up? That's cool"` or `"What's up, that's cool"`.

```py
pattern = r'\s*(bro|girl)[,.!?\s]*'
text = re.sub(pattern, ' ', text).strip()
```

I'm not very well-versed in regex; this only works for some cases. It'll miss strings like "You go girl! Go get them".

Comment: What's the expected output for that last string?

Comment: This is not a regex problem.  There are decisions here that require heuristics.  You can certainly find the "bro" and "girl", but you'll have to do some processing after that to consolidate the punctuation.  You'll also have to decide which of those two approaches you want.  The computer can't make that up.

Comment: It does not miss the string `"You go girl! Go get them"` right? See https://regex101.com/r/3eZk4v/1 Your expected results can be quite different, can you update the question with some clear examples and expected results?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following pattern:

`pattern = r"\b(bro|girl)\b[\s\W]*"`

This will select all matches of the words "bro" and "girl" that are surrounded by word boundaries (using the \b command) and any number of whitespace or non-word characters (using the [\s\W]* command). Check the example of the case below:

```
import re

text1 = "What's up, bro? That's cool"
text2 = "You go girl! Go get them"
pattern = r"\b(bro|girl)\b[\s\W]*"

result1 = re.sub(pattern, "", text1)
result2 = re.sub(pattern, "", text2)

print(result1) #What's up, That's cool
print(result2) #You go Go get them
```